# How to get the real declared types of member varaibles of a subclass of Generic[T]

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

I am trying to get the real type of a variable of Generic Type. I tried many ways, however, none of them looks promising.

Here is the minimal code that demenstrates my question:

```py
from typing import *
T = TypeVar('T')

class G(Generic[T]):
    x: T = None

class R(G[int]):
    pass
```

I want to get the real type of `R.x` in runtime. My first try is using `get_type_hints`. It gives

```py
{'x': ~T}
```

Looks not very useful.

I also tried with `R.__orig_bases__`. It does have something:

```py
(__main__.G[int],)
```

But it is too complex to align base class type arguments to member variables.

Do you guys have ways to get the real type of `R.x` in runtime? Is it possible?

Comment: Runtime inspection of anything from the `typing` module is still in a pretty terrible state. There's no documented introspection API for almost anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given that `R` inherits specifically `G[int]`, there's really no need to fetch the inner type at runtime: you know it's specifically int, so you can just hard-code that everywhere.

You could also always do `type(instance_of_r.x)`. Presumably, you defined `R.__init__` in such a way that you've guaranteed `x` is instantiated with a value of the right type, so you can just query that directly.

However, if you're trying to work with multiple subclasses of `G[...]`, where each subclass parameterizes `G[...]` in a different way, you could potentially modify the definition of `G` to insist that each subclass specifies the type you want to use. For example, maybe you could do something roughly like this:

```
from typing import *
T = TypeVar('T')

class G(Generic[T]):
    x_type: ClassVar[Type[T]]
    x: T = None

class R(G[int]):
    x_type = int

class S(G[str]):
    x_type = str
```

Then, you could do `instance_of_g.x_type` to get back the appropriate type.

You could perhaps combine these two answers -- for example, maybe set up `G`'s constructor so that it calls `type(...)` on whatever value of `x` it was given.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want. For example, `T` can be `Optional[T]`, and you can't just `type` it to get its real declared type. The other solution is just too intrusive, and I'm afraid I don't want to use it.

Comment: @XUWeijiang -- Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there really are any other solutions to your problem: type hints were not really designed with runtime inspection in mind. (In fact, I'd argue they were at least in part intentionally designed to make this kind of thing difficult.) I suppose if push comes to shove, one strategy of last resort would be to convert the contents of `R.__orig_bases__` into a string, parse it, and recover what the underlying type ought to be yourself.